# Where can I find a list of scope selectors for Aptana Studio 3's syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax, scope, selector, aptana, highlighting

Does anyone know if there's a comprehensive list somewhere of all of the possible scope selectors used for Aptana's syntax highlighting? I'd also love to see any documentation on how they're used, since they seem to have their own syntactic quirks.

When I export a theme, it saves in a .tmTheme format, so the scope selectors may be more related to that file format than to Aptana itself. I've searched the web quite a bit about this but can't seem to find anything useful. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any such list, but you can put your cursor on or highlight the text that you want to know the scope for. Right-click there, then Show In > Properties. A Properties view should then appear. In the Properties view, in the row with property Scope, there will be a value like "source.js" (or likely something more complicated). You could then copy and paste that value to a document.

So, you could go about making your list this way, even if tedious. But if you asked this question because you're like me and just needed to add a few JavaScript theme elements, the process shouldn't be so bad. You:

1. copy the scope selector from the Properties view,
2. paste it in Notepad or the like (as I myself couldn't precisely copy it and leave out the word "Scope" from the row),
3. copy just the scope-selector part from the note app,
4. in Themes press the plus sign (+) that's to the left of "Scope Selector,"
5. right-click and paste into the Scope Selector field,
6. left-click "untitled" and name the element accordingly,
7. press Enter and then go ahead and modify FG etc.

As a side note, some people coming across this question and then going through the steps might then have the very specific issue of not being able to get their .js JavaScript to look like their .html-/.php-embedded JavaScript. For whatever reason, they have a lot of JS in one of their HTML or PHP files and were trying to change the JS variable colors from there instead from a JS file. The editor scope of a JavaScript variable in .php, for instance, is "text.html.basic source.js.embedded.html source.js." In .js it's just "source.js," and this alone will also work for the embedded JavaScript.

(I don't have a solution yet for having more fine-grained control over a few JavaScript elements. For instance, both a function call and a variable have an editor scope of "source.js." You can't give them distinct colors.... I imagine that would require being an Aptana Studio developer.)